# Embedded Apache FTP Server: Unable to authenticate client using DbUserManager

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I am trying to create an application which will have built-in/embedded FTP server using "Apache FTP Server". I opted for managing/authenticating users from MySQL database. So, I used DbUserManager for handling user creation, deletion and listing. I am able to manage all user related actions except authentication. I could not log in from FTP client. Server do not even asking for password and just giving message "Connection closed by remote host". One more observation is that - if the user is not in DB, then its asking for password, but finally giving authentication failed message.

Here is the code,

```
public class Dumper {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FtpServerFactory serverFactory;
    FtpServer server;

    ConnectionConfigFactory connectionConfigFactory;
    ConnectionConfig connectionConfig;

    DbUserManagerFactory userManagerFactory;
    DbUserManager userManager;
    BasicDataSource bdSource;

    final Map<String, Ftplet> ftpletMap;
    Ftplet ftplet;

    // TODO code application logic here
    System.out.println("I am Dumper!!");

    connectionConfigFactory = new ConnectionConfigFactory();
    connectionConfigFactory.setAnonymousLoginEnabled(true);
    connectionConfig = connectionConfigFactory.createConnectionConfig();

    ftpletMap = new HashMap<>();
    ftplet = new DumperLet();
    ftpletMap.put("default", ftplet);

    // Data Source 
    bdSource = new BasicDataSource();
    bdSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    bdSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apsdma");
    bdSource.setUsername("apsdma");
    bdSource.setPassword("apsdma");

    // Database User Manager
    userManagerFactory = new DbUserManagerFactory();
    userManagerFactory.setPasswordEncryptor(new Md5PasswordEncryptor());
    userManagerFactory.setAdminName("ambedkar");

    userManagerFactory.setDataSource(bdSource);
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserInsert("INSERT INTO FTP_USER (userid, userpassword, homedirectory, enableflag, writepermission, idletime,uploadrate, downloadrate) VALUES ('{userid}', '{userpassword}', '{homedirectory}', {enableflag}, {writepermission}, {idletime}, {uploadrate}, {downloadrate})");
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserUpdate("UPDATE FTP_USER SET userpassword='{userpassword}', homedirectory='{homedirectory}', enableflag={enableflag}, writepermission={writepermission}, idletime={idletime}, uploadrate={uploadrate}, downloadrate={downloadrate} WHERE userid='{userid}'");
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserDelete("DELETE FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid = '{userid}'");
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserSelect("SELECT userid, userpassword, homedirectory, enableflag, writepermission, idletime, uploadrate, downloadrate FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid = '{userid}'");
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserSelectAll("SELECT userid FROM FTP_USER ORDER BY userid");
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserAdmin("SELECT userid FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid='{userid}' AND userid='ambedkar'");
    userManagerFactory.setSqlUserAuthenticate("SELECT userpassword from FTP_USER WHERE userid='{userid}'");

    userManager = (DbUserManager) userManagerFactory.createUserManager();

    serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();
    serverFactory.setConnectionConfig(connectionConfig);
    serverFactory.setFtplets(ftpletMap);
    serverFactory.setUserManager(userManager);
    server = serverFactory.createServer();

    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (FtpException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Dumper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the client output,
[image: [1]]

Can someone guide me what went wrong or where to look for solution please...

Answer (score 0):

is the "enableflag" field set to FALSE or 1 in the database? if you used the provided sql file for creating the table, this field is set to TRUE by default.

Regards

Comment: Making an answer when you still have doubts about the details of the question is somewhat daring. I recommend to start by answering questions which are clear to you. Asking for clarification before answering should be done in the shape of comments, which will be available to you after a few upvoted or accepted answers.